# Avoid PopupWindow grabbing focus

Tags: android, popupwindow

I have an EditText which updates a PopupWindow on each keypress. If I create the PopupWIndow with .setFocusable(true), then it grabs focus and I can't keep typing. However, if I use .setFocusable(false), the ListView inside the PopupWindow does not trigger the OnItemClickedListener.

Is it posible create a PopupWindow without it grabbing focus, but still make widgets inside it clickable?

(The PopupWidow is not for autocomplete, so I don't think AutoCompleteTextView is what I need)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can use ListPopupWindow. It handle some focus issues for you. Here is a very simple code. It still has to add more listeners to fit your need. But it figures focus issues out.

```
ListPopupWindow popup;
EditText editText;
String[] strAry = {"a", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};

editText=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText);
popup= new ListPopupWindow(this.getApplicationContext());
popup.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,strAry));
popup.setAnchorView(editText);
popup.setInputMethodMode(ListPopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);

editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View eventView) {
        if(!popup.isShowing()){
            popup.setInputMethodMode(ListPopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
            popup.show();
        }
    }
});
editText.addTextChangedListener(new s(){
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        if(!popup.isShowing()){
            popup.setInputMethodMode(ListPopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
            popup.postShow();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using PopupWindow i also face the same problem if any solution with PopupWindow. Please share.